# Mobx Class Cannot read property 'loading' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Used create-react-app to create the react-app

So I'am using mobx with react and created the following class:

```
import { action, decorate, observable } from "mobx";

class AuthStore {
  loading = false;

  login() {
    console.log(this.loading);
  }
}

decorate(AuthStore, {
  loading: observable,
  login: action
});

export default AuthStore;
```

And it says that loading is undefined but I have no clue why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn't saying `loading` is undefined, its saying that `this` is.

The value of `this` depends on the context in which `login` is called, not by where it is declared. I don't see `login` being called within the class, which means it won't refer to the class instance.

The simplest solution would be to convert the function to arrow syntax which uses lexical scope (it will have `this` as referring to the class).

```js
login = () => {
  console.log(this.loading);
}
```

The other, less terse solution, would be to manually bind `this` to the function in the constructor.

```js
class AuthStore {
  constructor() {
    this.login = this.login.bind(this)
  }

  loading = false;

  login() {
    console.log(this.loading);
  }
}
```

It will have the same effect.